# ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import csv data to a table using MySQL 5.22. My data file has 3 columns and several lines. The 3r d column contains integers with one or two digits.

```
mysql> LOAD DATA local INFILE 'my_data_filename.csv'       
-> REPLACE INTO TABLE mysql_tabe_name     
-> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','     
-> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';  
                                                                                              ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '"thirdcol"' for column 'thirdcol' at row 1
```

Comment: Your [MCVE] should include the table schema and the data you're importing. Otherwise it is clearly impossible for us to diagnose this issue. All you've done is shown us a textbook example of a basic MySQL command that we all know works on its own. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The error is obvious, but lets make sure you know it... On your database there is a field which should only contain numbers (integer), yet from your .cvs file you are trying to import something else there.

You probably can find the incorrect data by checking the last imported row from database, bad data is obviously on the next row. (Error message should contain the info about this, but you did not include it to your question)

If mysql/database does not tell which value it is that is wrong, you can split your .cvs file in to two pieces and try to pinpoint the row containing wrong data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actualy after looking into it it worked.